# Latex: usepackage{tikz} is resulting in undefined color error for 'black'

Tags: latex, tikz

When I compile

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
Package xcolor Error : Undefined color `n'
l.113 \pgfutil@colorlet{pgftransparent}{black}
```

I am using the latest distribution of Miktex with all the updates. Can you please help me get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Thanks for looking into this question. I was having a local xcolor.sty file which was an old version and interfering with the compilation of tikz package. Everything fell in line after I deleted the xcolor.sty. Thanks.